React Vite PostCSS syntax error upon installing Shadcn Sidebar
I have a Vite+React+Typescript project where I wast trying to follow the instructions on how to install sidebar.
It automatically added some styles to my index.css file. Now, the content pretty much looks like this:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200..1000;1,200..1000&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --primary: 0 0% 9%;
    --primary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --secondary: 0 0% 96.1%;
    --secondary-foreground: 0 0% 9%;
    --muted: 0 0% 96.1%;
    --muted-foreground: 0 0% 45.1%;
    --accent: 0 0% 96.1%;
    --accent-foreground: 0 0% 9%;
    --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
    --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --border: 0 0% 89.8%;
    --input: 0 0% 89.8%;
    --ring: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --chart-1: 12 76% 61%;
    --chart-2: 173 58% 39%;
    --chart-3: 197 37% 24%;
    --chart-4: 43 74% 66%;
    --chart-5: 27 87% 67%;
    --radius: 0.5rem;
    --sidebar-background: 0 0% 98%;
    --sidebar-foreground: 240 5.3% 26.1%;
    --sidebar-primary: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --sidebar-primary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --sidebar-accent: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --sidebar-accent-foreground: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --sidebar-border: 220 13% 91%;
    --sidebar-ring: 217.2 91.2% 59.8%;
  }
  .dark {
    --background: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --card: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --card-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --popover: 0 0% 3.9%;
    --popover-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --primary: 0 0% 98%;
    --primary-foreground: 0 0% 9%;
    --secondary: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --secondary-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --muted: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --muted-foreground: 0 0% 63.9%;
    --accent: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --accent-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
    --destructive-foreground: 0 0% 98%;
    --border: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --input: 0 0% 14.9%;
    --ring: 0 0% 83.1%;
    --chart-1: 220 70% 50%;
    --chart-2: 160 60% 45%;
    --chart-3: 30 80% 55%;
    --chart-4: 280 65% 60%;
    --chart-5: 340 75% 55%;
    --sidebar-background: 240 5.9% 10%;
    --sidebar-foreground: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --sidebar-primary: 224.3 76.3% 48%;
    --sidebar-primary-foreground: 0 0% 100%;
    --sidebar-accent: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
    --sidebar-accent-foreground: 240 4.8% 95.9%;
    --sidebar-border: 240 3.7% 15.9%;
    --sidebar-ring: 217.2 91.2% 59.8%;
  }

  * {
    @apply border-border;
  }

  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground;
  }
}

.firebase-emulator-warning {
  @apply hidden;
}

The problem is, when I run Vite in dev mode, it gives me an error saying:
11:33:52 PM [vite] Internal server error: [postcss] Unexpected token, expected "," (9:31)
  Plugin: vite:css
  File: /src/index.css:undefined:NaN
  9  |  @tailwind utilities;
  10 |  
  11 |  @layer base {
     |   ^
  12 |    :root {
  13 |      --background: 0 0% 100%;
      at unexpected (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/util.js:99:15)
      at expect (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/util.js:86:5)
      at parseObj (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:759:20)
      at parseExprAtom (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:553:7)
      at parseExprSubscripts (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:276:20)
      at parseMaybeUnary (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:257:20)
      at parseExprOps (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:185:20)
      at parseMaybeConditional (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:157:20)
      at baseParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:142:20)
      at tsParseMaybeAssignWithoutJSX (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1580:45)
      at tsParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1548:12)
      at parseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:121:43)
      at parseObjectProperty (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:851:7)
      at parseObjPropValue (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:892:5)
      at parseObj (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:808:5)
      at parseExprAtom (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:553:7)
      at parseExprSubscripts (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:276:20)
      at parseMaybeUnary (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:257:20)
      at parseExprOps (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:185:20)
      at parseMaybeConditional (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:157:20)
      at baseParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:142:20)
      at tsParseMaybeAssignWithoutJSX (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1580:45)
      at tsParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1548:12)
      at parseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:121:43)
      at parseObjectProperty (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:851:7)
      at parseObjPropValue (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:892:5)
      at parseObj (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:808:5)
      at parseExprAtom (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:553:7)
      at parseExprSubscripts (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:276:20)
      at parseMaybeUnary (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:257:20)
      at parseExprOps (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:185:20)
      at parseMaybeConditional (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:157:20)
      at baseParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:142:20)
      at tsParseMaybeAssignWithoutJSX (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1580:45)
      at tsParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1548:12)
      at parseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:121:43)
      at parseObjectProperty (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:851:7)
      at parseObjPropValue (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:892:5)
      at parseObj (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:808:5)
      at parseExprAtom (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:553:7)
      at parseExprSubscripts (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:276:20)
      at parseMaybeUnary (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:257:20)
      at parseExprOps (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:185:20)
      at parseMaybeConditional (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:157:20)
      at baseParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:142:20)
      at tsParseMaybeAssignWithoutJSX (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1580:45)
      at tsParseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/plugins/typescript.js:1548:12)
      at parseMaybeAssign (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/expression.js:121:43)
      at parseExportDefaultExpression (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/statement.js:1024:34)
      at parseExport (/node_modules/sucrase/dist/parser/traverser/statement.js:988:5)
11:33:52 PM [vite] Pre-transform error: [postcss] Unexpected token, expected "," (9:31)

It says there is a syntax error but I don't see anything wrong with it. Why does it give this error?

I have got the same error couples of days back for postcss file. But the real error was in my tailwind.config.ts, there was a syntax error for font-family array. It previously looked like below:
font-family: [sans-serif\n   ,inter\n,   ......]
i have made it to:
font-family: [sans-serif, inter.....]
An then i ran 'convert indentation to spaces' in vscode command pallete(cntrl+shift+p). And then it solved my error.

Yep, the error is with tailwind.config.ts, but error weirdly point out CSS for it for some reason. And also there seems to be an issue for this. Thank you.
